# When i use Invoke to a method i want to use i can't call it anymore?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I started to learn coding myself by watching videos, reading web articles etc. and i thought that learning by doing would suit better for me so i started to make a game with Unity through Brackeys tutorial videos.

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class gameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool hasGameEnded = false;

    public float restartDelay = 1f;
    public void endGame()
    {
        if (hasGameEnded == false)
        {
            
            hasGameEnded = true;
            Invoke("Restart", 2f);
        }

        void Restart()
        {

            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

        }

    }
```

So my problem here is when i use invoke with the method Restart none of the callings works.
"Warning    CS8321  The local function 'Restart' is declared but never used" Thats the error i get.

If wanted i can show where and how i used the endGame method. Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: You have declared `Restart` as a method INSIDE `endGame` method. Try moving it out of there (out to the class). And when calling `Invoke` Restart should not be in quotes.

Comment: Poul Bak has given you the right answer.  I just wanted to say you got a warning, not an error.  Code will still compile with Warnings and run, but not always work.  My advice is keep on treating them as errors and fix them, don't listen to the 'experts' who say you can ignore Warnings, because as you have just found thats not always true :)

Comment: Thanks for you kind answers. I did what you and Mohammad said and it worked as it should. The only thing Poul said wrong was Restart should be in quotes. I tried it without quotes and it didn't worked and of course Gorilla i'll not ignore Warnings even if it is just one Warning. Thanks for your long term advice !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### If the `Void` Was inside another `Void` it wont work.

**So you need to change :**

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class gameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool hasGameEnded = false;

    public float restartDelay = 1f;
    public void endGame()
    {
        if (hasGameEnded == false)
        {
            
            hasGameEnded = true;
            Invoke("Restart", 2f);
        }

        void Restart()
        {

            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

        }

    }

}
```

**To :**

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class gameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool hasGameEnded = false;

    public float restartDelay = 1f;
    public void endGame()
    {
        if (hasGameEnded == false)
        {
            
            hasGameEnded = true;
            Invoke("Restart", 2f);
        }
    }

    void Restart()
    {

        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your exampled solution and explanation !