# invoke() Function in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Its almost my first time using C sharp and unity. I am trying to use invoke() function in unity but its giving the error

> "Trying to Invoke method: EndGame.Restart1 couldn't be called."

```
public class EndGame : MonoBehaviour
{ 
    bool GameHasEnded = false;
    public float Timer = 1f;
    
    public void endgame() 
    {        
        if (!GameHasEnded) 
        {
            GameHasEnded = true;
            Debug.Log("GameOver");
            Invoke("Restart", Timer);
        }
   
        void Restart()
        { 
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would need the endgame instance to call restart or to change it to be static

Comment: This is weird, I found the same question yesterday, You can check the answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65526960/when-i-use-invoke-to-a-method-i-want-to-use-i-cant-call-it-anymore/65528292#65528292

Answer (score 1):

- You are trying to `Invoke` a [local method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) that is nested inside of another method `endgame`.

  Afaik [`MonoBehaviour.Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html) can only call methods on class level.
- It also is either a typo here or in your original code but `Restart1` doesn't exist only `Restart`. To avoid typos in name based code I would use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof)

Your code should rather look like

```c#
public class EndGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool GameHasEnded = false;

    // Timer is strange name for that
    // I would suggest "Delay"
    public float Delay = 1f;

    public void endgame()
    {         
        if (!GameHasEnded)
        {
            GameHasEnded = true;
            Debug.Log("GameOver");

            // In general in order to avoid typos I would prefer to use "nameof"
            Invoke(nameof(Restart), Delay);
        }
    }

    private void Restart()
    {       
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to call a void inside another void?

Comment: Don't mind, I found the answer